# IPC for Java programs using Windows' Named Pipes using JNI

Tags: java, c, winapi, java-native-interface

I am creating a Java class using JNI that allows various IPC mechanisms between separate Java programs.

I've created a class called `WindowsIPC` that contains a native method that can access Windows' **named pipes**. I have a native function called `createNamedPipeServer()` that calls `CreateNamedPipe`. It appears to have created the pipe correctly as I can view it using a tool such as Process Explorer.

My problem is that when I make use of this in a separate Java program and making use of a separate thread to read and write data using Java's standard Input and output streams, it fails. I can **write** data to the pipe successfully but cannot read the contents; it returns with a `FileNotFoundException (All pipe instances are busy)`.

I am struggling to wrap my head around this as I cannot figure out what other process is using the pipe as well as the fact that I've specified `PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES` when the pipe was created.
I have read up extensively on how reads work and my hunch is that input/output streams in Java handle it due to the fact that it is returning the error mentioned above.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

**WindowIPC.java**

```
public class WindowsIPC {
  public native int createNamedPipeServer(String pipeName);
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("WindowsIPC");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // some testing..
  }
}
```

**WindowsIPC.c**

```
const jbyte *nameOfPipe; // global variable representing the named pipe
HANDLE pipeHandle; // global handle..

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_WindowsIPC_createNamedPipeServer
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring pipeName) {
    jint retval = 0;
    char buffer[1024]; // data buffer of 1K
    DWORD cbBytes;

    // Get the name of the pipe
    nameOfPipe = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, pipeName, NULL);

    pipeHandle = CreateNamedPipe (
      nameOfPipe,                      // name of the pipe
      PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
      PIPE_TYPE_BYTE |
      PIPE_READMODE_BYTE |
      PIPE_NOWAIT,                    // forces a return, so thread doesn't block
      PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
      1024,
      1024,
      0,
      NULL
    );

    // error creating server
    if (pipeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) retval = -1;
    else printf("Server created successfully: name:%s\n", nameOfPipe);

    // waits for a client -- currently in ASYC mode so returns immediately
    jboolean clientConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(pipeHandle, NULL);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, pipeName, nameOfPipe);
    return retval;
}
```

And finally **TestWinIPC.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestWinIPC {
  public static void main (String[] args)
    {

      WindowsIPC winIPC = new WindowsIPC();

      // TEST NAMED PIPES
      final String pipeName = "\\\\.\\Pipe\\JavaPipe";

      if (winIPC.createNamedPipeServer(pipeName) == 0) {
        System.out.println("named pipe creation succeeded");
        Thread t = new Thread(new NamedPipeThread(pipeName));
        t.start();
        try {
          System.out.println("opening pipe for input");
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pipeName)));
          System.out.println("waiting to read");
          String line = br.readLine();
          System.out.println("Read from pipe OK: " + line);
          br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {
          System.err.println("I/O Error: " + exc);
          exc.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
} //main

private static class NamedPipeThread implements Runnable {
    private String pipeName;

    public NamedPipeThread (String pipeName) {
      this.pipeName = pipeName;
    } // constructor

    public void run () {
     try {
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(pipeName));
         pw.println("Hello Pipe");
         System.out.println("Wrote to named pipe OK");
         pw.close();
      }
      catch (IOException exc) {
          System.err.println("I/O Error: " + exc);
          exc.printStackTrace();
      }
    } // run
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can a FileOutputStream/FileInputStream access a named pipe as a server? If it uses CreateFile internally it will connect as a client only, meaning there would be no server to write any data through the named pipe.

Comment: In your `createNamedPipeServer()` function, you always call `ConnectNamedPipe` even if `pipeHandle` is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. I don't think that would cause the problems you're seeing, but you probably should fix that anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is noted - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting an "all pipe instances are busy" error is that you're connecting to the pipe twice (once for reading and once for writing) but you've only created one instance.  (Note that using the PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES option allows you to create as many instances as you like, but you still have to create them yourself.)

From the looks of it, you were expecting the the call to `FileInputStream` to open the server end of the pipe.  That's not how it works.  You must use the handle returned from `CreateNamedPipe` in order to access the server end of the pipe.

Whether there is a straightforward, supported way to convert a handle into a stream in JNI I have no idea (there doesn't seem to be so far as I can tell) but note that the fact that it is a nonblocking handle is likely to be a complication, since Java almost certainly won't be expecting that.

A more promising approach would be to implement `InputStream` and/or `OutputStream` classes that call JNI methods to do the actual I/O.

*Addendum:* if you don't want to use JNI, and can't find any more acceptable way of converting a native handle into a stream, you could in principle launch a (native) thread to tie the server ends of two separate pipes together, allowing the client ends to talk to one another.  I'm not sure that would perform any better than using JNI, but I suppose it might be worth trying.

---

There is one other technical problem with your code: in non-blocking mode, you are expected to call `ConnectNamedPipe` repeatedly until it reports that a pipe is connected:

> Note that a good connection between client and server exists only after the ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED error is received.

In practice, you can probably get away without doing this, provided you're not planning to reuse the pipe instance for another client.  Windows implicitly connects the first client for any given pipe instance, so you don't need to call `ConnectNamedPipe` at all.  However, you should note that this is an undocumented feature.

It probably makes more sense to use normal I/O and issue the call to `ConnectNamedPipe` the first time the Java code asks you to do I/O; presumably, the programmer will be expecting the read and/or write operations to block anyway.

If you do not want to use normal I/O, you should prefer asynchronous I/O to nonblocking I/O:

> Nonblocking mode is supported for compatibility with Microsoft LAN Manager version 2.0, and it should not be used to achieve asynchronous input and output (I/O) with named pipes.

(Both quotes from [the MSDN page on ConnectNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I try to create another pipe instance using `createNamedPipeServer`, it gets rid of the All Pipes Busy problem but the program just hangs and doesn't read. I actually wanted to try avoid using JNI to do the actual I/O since there is a significant performance loss in doing so. When you say "call `ConnectNamedPipe` the first time the Java code asks you to do I/O", do you mean call a JNI method that does so?

Comment: *but the program just hangs and doesn't read* - as expected, since there's nothing writing to the server end of the pipe.  You need to understand this before going any further, it sounds like you don't have a clear picture of how Windows pipes work yet.  (FWIW, I've added another possible solution to my answer.  But you will need to understand how pipes work to use it effectively.)

Comment: As for the potential issue with `ConnectNamedPipe`, I suggest that for the time being you take advantage of the fact that it is in practice optional to call `ConnectNamedPipe` at all.  If you remove that call, you no longer need to use `PIPE_NOWAIT` which is an unnecessary complication.  You can come back to this once you've figured out what your options are for getting the I/O to work.